# Match Domain without www/com/co.uk - Regex

Tags: php, regex

I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find anything that works!

Basically I need to match the domain name without www/com/http etc...

So, these links:

> http://www.google.com
>
> https://www.google.com
>
> http://www.google.co.uk
>
> https://www.google.co.uk

Should match as simply `google`.

This is what I have got so far:

```
^(?:http:\/\/)(?:www[.])(.*?)[.]
```

If I change it to `https` things go pear shaped.

Comment: Use [`^https?:\/\/www\.([^.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/0AmFmQ/1)

Comment: What about subdomains? `http://www.images.google.com`

Comment: The *domain name* is www.google.co.uk (for instance). You can parse that out with any URL-parsing library/tool/function. What you want is the part of it most interesting to humans, which is an extremely wishy-washy concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^https?:\/\/www\.([^.]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0AmFmQ/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `http` - a literal substring
- `s?` - 1 or  0 `s` chars
- `:\/\/www\.` - a literal `://www.` substring
- `([^.]+)` - Group 1: any 1 or more chars other than `.` (the `[^...]` is a [**negated character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated))